# How to filter the results of a query in postgresql when using CAST and SUBSTRING (pgAdmin 4)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and have a table that has a string that is made of numbers and text (e.g., "10 Windows").  From this table, I need to extract out the "10" from the string and move it into a new column as an integer (I'm using pgAdmin4)

I was able to write a query to parse out the numbers from the string and return them to a new column as an integer.

```
SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
FROM events
```

From here, I can get the numbers from the string in data1 into a column named data1_num as an integer.

However, if I want to filter to find say, all of the rows that where data1_num = 27, by the query below, I get an error.

```
SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
FROM events
WHERE data1_num = 27
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "data1_num" does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE data1_num = 27
          ^
 ********** Error **********

 ERROR: column "data1_num" does not exist
 SQL state: 42703
 Character: 205
```

Am I missing something?

I feel that this should work and even if there were zero rows where data1_num was 27, I should not get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your `SELECT` clause appears first in a query, it is actually *evaluated* after the `WHERE` clause. That's standard SQL. This means you can't access the computed columns (or column aliases) on your `SELECT`.

Just try this:

```
SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
FROM events
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) = 27 ;
```

NOTE: don't worry about expressions being computed twice. It's up to the database to optimize that.

If you still worry, you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
        FROM events
    ) AS q
WHERE data1_num = 27 ;
```

---

References:

- [Conceptual Order of Evaluation of a Select Statement](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because how a query is parsed in postgresql. First the where condition is checked, followed by group by and order by statements (if any), and then at last the list of columns get selected. So postgres is not able to recognize the alias.

I think this would give you the desired result:

```
SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
FROM events
WHERE SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') = '27'
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because column "data1_num" is a virtual column, if you want to get result then you have to write the same cast logic in where clause.

```
SELECT data1, CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) AS data1_num
FROM events
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(data1 FROM '(\d+)') AS INTEGER) = 27
```